# Moving a Team Project from one Collection to another

Tags: tfs, team-project

is there a (simple) way to move a single TeamProject from one collection to another (in one server) in TFS 2010? Including source code, work items, documents, project site...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "TFS:" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: For TFS 2012 check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137317/how-to-copy-a-team-project-from-one-collection-to-another-with-tfs-integration-p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No not really simple, you can split a collection and creata a new collection with the team projects you move in it, but you cannot out-of-the-box merge a team project into an existing collection.

What you can do is to use the TFS integration platform http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe or http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com to migrate your team project over to the new collection. This is however a DataMigration that doesnt keep or even move all data, but it will move Source Code & Workitems.  Moving a team project site (if needed) , including documents can be done by using the STSADM Export and Import commands, please refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288191%28v=office.12%29.aspx for more info about moving SharePoint sites

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't.

But it is a requested feature: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te

Answer (score 3):

It is not easy, but it is doable: [Split a Team Project Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158.aspx)

Comment: Split a Team Project Collection made two TeamProject collections in Team Foundation Server, but i want to move a single TeamProject from one collection to another.

Comment: Ah. sorry, misread your question. That is not possible since a team project is not a logical artifact in the database. Your only option then is indeed the Integration Platform to migrate data. Just curious: why do you want to move your team project?

Comment: After Upgrading Team Foundation Server 2008 to 2010, we created a new Collection named OldProject. 
Then, we created new collections named, MobileCollection, DesktopCollection, DataProcessingCollection, RndCollection, and WebCollecton, for each units of software. 
This leds to each programmer is involved in two or more different Collections.

Comment: Switching between collections is undesirable for programmers and due to this reason we are gonging to remove OldProjects collection and transfer projects of OldProjects collection to others collections.

Comment: So you want to merge multiple collections into one.

Comment: NO,i want split OldPrrojects collection to multiple collections

Comment: There is a MSDN article how to split a collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158.aspx

Comment: this web page representation splitting a collection to new multiple collections

Comment: So you want to move team projects from OldProjects to other existing colletions?

Comment: yes,I want to move team projects from OldProjects collection to other existing collection

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a feature request, but I don't think it will be shipped in the box, so the other option to use [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to move from one collection to another using git-tfs and git-tf tools, it is a kind of workaround, but works if this is really required to be done.

This is posted step-by-step here:
https://fabiostawinski.wordpress.com/2017/03/22/tfvc-to-git-to-tfvc-is-it-possible/

Answer (score -1):

In VS 2013 - map both collections to some folders, and then "Move" command will be available:

[image]

Comment: Will this move history too?

Comment: Mmm.. As I remember - Yes. Try it with test project.

Comment: The solution above will work for moving files/folders/etc. between multiple Team Projects; but I cannot get it to work for moving entire Team Projects from one collection to another

Comment: move single team project to other collection? or not folder.