# Project synchronization between TFS 2010 and local TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, synchronization, migration

We have remote client TFS 2010 and want create our local TFS 2012(that have sweet agile tools) with our repository and some branches for future tools/test and builds. Is there simple way for action synchronization between our local tfs 2012 and there remote tfs 2010.

I read about [Moving a TFS 2010 project to TFS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100406/moving-a-team-project-from-one-collection-to-another) and [Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) but mb there some updates?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible with the TFS Integration Platform Tools, as you suggested (http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

The tool supports a continuously running synchronization service, but it is a complicated process where changesets are basically "played-back" checkins from source to target. So all synchronized changesets will be checked in with a new timestamp.

I can recommend http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/ which has a lot of posts regarding TFSIP.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2012/05/23/msdn-magazine-migrating-from-an-on-premise-tfs-to-tfs-preview-using-the-tfs-integration-tools.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/11/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-1.aspx