# How to copy a team project from one collection to another with TFS Integration Platform, TFS2012 to TFS2012

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I've downloaded the latest TFS Integration Platform from CodePlex and attempted to migrate "one way" between an existing team project `MyProject` in `CollectionA` on the left and an empty team project `MyProject` in `CollectionB` on the right using the provided "source control and work item" template. Whenever I do, it raises a few exceptions about the build templates (I resolve them), and then it displays this wonderful-looking diagram of changesets with bar graphs, and I feel like it's done something. Every time I try this, I look at `MyProject` in source control in `CollectionB` expecting to see a fully-populated version of the project from `CollectionA`. Every time, I am disappointed - it's empty and it looks like nothing happened.

By the way, I am try to move the project from between collections on the same TFS 2012 server.

Am I misunderstanding the point of Integration Platform? Or does it just not actually work with TFS 2012?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, here's how I did it.

Suppose I am trying to copy a project `MyProject` from `SourceCollection` to `TargetCollection`.

1. Create a new project `MyProject` in `TargetCollection`
2. Open [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)
3. Under Configuration select "Create New"
4. Open folder "Team Foundation Server" (%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server Integration Tools\Configurations\Team Foundation Server)
5. Select "VersionControl.xml" or "VersionControlAndWorkItemTracking.xml" if you need it (if you choose to include WorkItem tracking as well ensure the account you started TFS Integration is a user which is in the "Team Foundation Service Accounts" TFS Global Group)
6. Workflow type: Custom / Frequency: One-time / Direction: Unidirectional / Sync context: disabled (your selection may differ)
7. Left source: "TFS 11 Migration VC Provider"
8. Pick the existing project `MyProject` in `SourceCollection`
9. Right source: "TFS 11 Migration VC Provider"
10. Pick the new project `MyProject` in `TargetCollection`
11. **Important: you must include any folders (paths) under the root explicitly and individually in the folders list. Just using $/ or $/MyProject will not work**. For example, if you have folders `src/` and `test/` under the root, you must include these as `$/MyProject/src` and `$/MyProject/test`. Ensure that you also create those folders in `MyProject` in `TargetCollection`.
12. Save to database
13. Start migration
14. Handle any exceptions

You are done.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but I'm trying to migrate between two TFServices. Please have a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134711/migrating-moving-tfservice-to-tfservice-visualstudio-com)

Comment: It worked for me for migrating Source Code only in TFS 2012 from one Collection to another Collection.

Comment: The explanation is not clear to me. I couldn't find this Configuration thing that tacos is talking about. Can someone please add some screenshots for the steps?