# Migrating TFService to TFService (visualstudio.com)

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

Some projects we're working on are hosted on a TFS on visualstudio.com. However, the owner is an early adopter account that will expire soon. We already have another TFS in place (also on visualstudio.com), and now we want to migrate the code and version history from TFService A to TFService B.

I've tried using the TFS Integration Tool (http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) and created a configuration to migrate between the two subdomains on visualstudio.com. However, despite the tool indicating succesful migration, nothing actually changes on the destination server. I've found this question on SO:

[How to copy a team project from one collection to another with TFS Integration Platform, TFS2012 to TFS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137317/how-to-copy-a-team-project-from-one-collection-to-another-with-tfs-integration-p)

I have basically the same issue as the OP, but the answer does not work for me. What can I do?

Comment: Did you follow step 11 (the bolded step)? I was experiencing the exact same behavior until I did. It doesn't know what to do with `$/MyProjectName` so I had to manually enter each subfolder. Have you tried migrating a single subfolder?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos well, I added all the folders that were directly under the root and even one folder with one more underneath (`trunk/src`), but that didn't do it. there were files under `trunk/src`, they were not copied. I'm clueless but it looks like this tool does not work correctly with TFService.

Comment: Is there a way to copy your TFService to a TFS instance, and then back to TFService?

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this issue?

Comment: @jDub I contacted Microsoft directly and even they say there is no way.. Anyway I just checked the code into the new TFS so we lost the history but it's better than nothing.