# TFS2013 move project between collections

Tags: tfs

We use TFS 2013 as source control solution, and we need to move a project from collection to another, is there any way to move this project including check-ins and code review notes?

thanks and regards.

Comment: have a look at http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

Comment: If 2013 why do not use "Move"?
Answered here: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33563611/348736)

Answer (score 4):

There's no easy way to move team projects between two existing collections. You can try [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) but it's not an easy task. You can also consider [Splitting Team Project Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158(v=vs.120).aspx) so that you can delete your project from the original collection but it will stay in the new one (of course it will only work if you don't have the target collection right now).

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33563611/305916, mapping the two collections to the same folder, will introduce a "Move..." menu item...